# Wordpress login redirect user based on language

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have a multilanguage wordpress membership site, with s2member and wpml plugins.

an example for the login page in Portuguese is:
http://example.com/wp-login?lang=pt-br

I want to redirect users after the login to the Portuguese welcome page, and not the default welcome page which is English.

Is there a way to add a parameter into the login page in wordpress? If so, how can I access this parameter for my redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but this is how I solved it.

I have a field in my database for the language of each user.

I added this to the functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'analyze_form_submit' );

function analyze_form_submit() {

    global $current_user;

    if (is_page(86)) {  // 86 is the welcome page after login in my case

       $affil_id =  $current_user->user_login;
       $query="SELECT lang FROM affil WHERE affil_id=:affil_id";
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
       $stmt->bindParam(':affil_id', $affil_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute(); 
       $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       $redirect = "http://example.com/welcome?lang=";

       switch($row['lang']) {
          case "ENG" : $redirect .= "en"; break;
          case "HEB": $redirect .= "he"; break;
          case "ES" : $redirect .= "es"; break;
          case "BR" : $redirect .= "pt-br"; break;
          default   : $redirect .= "pt-br"; 
       };

       wp_redirect( $redirect );
       exit;
  };
};
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.